# How to control if the predicate is given in the command prompt?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to do some operation in the list if the predicate returns true. But predicate is given as input in command line and it is a function. Let me give an example.

```
(define (delete-rows table predicate)
    do_something)
```

And the command line looks like this.

```
(delete-rows student-table
    (lambda (table row)
        (eq? (get table row 'name) 'ali)))
=> '(students (name id gpa) (ayse 2 3.7))
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You would have to use `read` and `eval` to convert it from text to data to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very naïve and inefficient implementation in Racket, just to get you on the right track:

```scm
(define (list-index e lst)
  (- (length lst) (length (memq e lst))))

(define (get table row col)
  (list-ref row (list-index col (second table))))

(define (delete-rows table pred)
  (list* (first table) 
         (second table)
         (filter (lambda (r) (not (pred table r))) (cddr table))))
```

then

```scm
(define student-table '(students (name id gpa) (ali 1 2) (ayse 2 3.7) (zalde 3 5)))
(delete-rows student-table (lambda (table row) (eq? (get table row 'name) 'ali)))
=> '(students (name id gpa) (ayse 2 3.7) (zalde 3 5))
```