# (scheme) predicate as an argument of a function

Tags: lambda, scheme, predicate

In scheme I want to implement a function that takes a predicate as an argument.

```
(define (delete-rows table predicate)
(filter predicate (cddr table)
)
)
```

this my function which filters a list depending on predicate
and I want to call function as follows

```
(delete-rows student-table
(lambda (table row) ;this is the predicate (two lines)
(eq? (get table row 'name) 'mehmet)))
```

But it gives an error like

```
filter: contract violation
expected: (any/c . -> . any/c)
given: #<procedure:...cuments\mumu.rkt:88:0>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23595759/1193075

Comment: he asked just a few minutes before me

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate takes 2 parameters (table, row), but `filter` will call the predicate with one parameter only (the element to process). Hence the error.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23595759/1193075) for a solution.